# Read objects content from hashmaps

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I need to save pairs (string,object) into a hashmap. Basically I managed to populate the hashmap but I don't know how to access the values stored into memory.
This is my code:

```
HashMap<String, speedDial> SDs = new HashMap<String, speedDial>();
speedDial sd  = new speedDial();
SDs.put(String.valueOf(temp),sd); whre temp is my index and sd my object
```

Then I fill in data into the sd reading them from an xml file.

When I debug the project with eclypse I can see the values are stored correctly into memory, but I've no idea how to retrive the string values associated to the object, see below the SD object format

```
class speedDial{ 
  String label, dirN;


  speedDial (String l, String dN) { 
    this.label = l; 
    this.dirN = dN; 
  } 
}
```

See the picture below: it highlights the data I'm trying to access!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umWsi.png)

When I try to access the hashmap and print it's values I only got the last one, I use the following:

```
for ( int k = 0; k <50; k++) {
       speedDial.printSD(SDs.get(String.valueOf(k)));
}
```

This is my printSD method taken from the speedDial class:

```
public static void printSD (speedDial SD) {
      System.out.println("Dir.N: " + SD.dirN + " Label: " + SD.label);

  }
```

And this is the output for all the 50 iterations, that is the last element I added to the hashmap in another for cycle that reads from a xml file.

Dir.N: 123450 Label: label5

Comment: See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a HashMap such as:

```
SpeedDial speedDial1 = new SpeedDial("test1", "test2");
SpeedDial speedDial2 = new SpeedDial("test3", "test4");
SpeedDial speedDial3 = new SpeedDial("test5", "test6");

HashMap<String, SpeedDial> exampleHashMap = new HashMap<>(3);
exampleHashMap.put("key1", speedDial1);
exampleHashMap.put("key2", speedDial2);
exampleHashMap.put("key3", speedDial3);
```

You can retrieve the value for a given key like so:

```
SpeedDial exampleOfGetValue = exampleHashMap.get("key1");
System.out.println(exampleOfGetValue.label);
System.out.println(exampleOfGetValue.dirN);
```

This outputs:

```
test1
test2
```

If you want to retrieve the **keys** for a given value then you could use something like:

```
public final <S, T> List<S> getKeysForValue(final HashMap<S, T> hashMap, final T value) {
    return hashMap.entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(value))
                  .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you call this function  like so:

```
List<String> exampleOfGetKeys = getKeysForValue(exampleHashMap, speedDial1);
System.out.println(exampleOfGetKeys);
```

It would output a list of all keys that have this value:

```
[key1]
```

Comment: for HashMap SDs I'm adding in each field i.e SDs.dirN and SDs.label a value so my hashmap will have at key 'n' an object with the pairs of above values. The question is how to access the values of this objects because if I do a get the response is: addsd.speedDial@21be6

Comment: @lorenz updated to match your question more precisely

Comment: thanks for your help, it's what I was looking for. But I've a strange behaviour: when I try to access the hashmap it's like there would be only the last value for my speedDial everywhere I look into the hashmap. I don't understand it's like the object it's not there anymore or that it's values got overwritten

Comment: @lorenz are you adding multiple values for the same key? If you try to do this, for example:

`hashmap.put("key1", "value1");`
`hashmap.put("key1", "value2");`

The new value `"value2"` will overwrite the previous value `"value1"` for the same key `"key1"`.

If you want to do this, you will need to create a `HashMap<Key, List<Value>>` instead.

Comment: you are right smthg goes wrong while reading the value from the xml

Answer (score 0):

The following code will iterate through the map and will store the key and values in two lists.

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList();
List<Object> values = new ArrayList();

for (Map.Entry<String, Object> speedDial: SDs.entrySet()) {
            Object speedDialValue = speedDial.getValue();
            String key= speedDial.getKey();
            keys.add(key);
            values.add(speedDialValue);
}
```

To retrieve the String value, typically getters are used as it is recommended to use the `private` modifier for your class attributes.

```
public class speedDial{ 

  private String label, dirN;


  public speedDial (String l, String dN) { 
     this.label = l; 
     this.dirN = dN; 
   } 

  public String getLabel(){
     return this.label;
   }

   public String getDirN(){
     return this.dirN;
   }
}
```

The you can simply use `yourObject.getLabel();` or `yourObject.getDirN();`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`SDs.keySet()` Gives you the Set of the keys of your HashMap
You can have the list of values using

```
for (String mapKey : SDs.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("key: "+mapKey+"  value: "+ SDs.get(mapKey).toString());
}
```

Yous have to write a toString() fonction for your speedDial